# It is possible to save only one column in a database table?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, helper

I want a helper which will save only one specific column in database table(not eav).

Comment: Can you give a scenario of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For example i have a table with a column named 'flag'.. and i want to update only the value in 'flag' without having to save the whole row.

Comment: If you can explain the whole task you wanna accomplish, we may be able to explain you clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study Magento DB classes and use them. They extend Zend DB adapters so you can do the same things. If data you want to save is part of a model, then you can safely set Model entity id and the updated field and save.

Comment: found it. thx for advice!

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure if you mean that but maybe you want to do it directly like that:

```
/**
 * Get the resource model
 */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/**
 * Retrieve the write connection
 */
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

/**
 * In your case I guess UPDATE something
 */ 
$query = "some-sql-query;

/**
 * Execute the query
 */
$writeConnection->query($query);
```